# Mysqli query fetching no records

Tags: php, stored-procedures, mysqli

I am trying to run a PHP script that uses mysqli library, but it fetches no results on the webhosting server while in my machine running WLAMP PHP 5.14 it works well.

Can you please tell me if the problem is related with mysqli and if there is a way to make it work for my case?.

The lines I am looking to make work look like this:

```
$sql = "call sp_give_me_data(null,null,null);";

if (!$mysqli->query($sql)) {
   die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
} else {

   $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $datainfo[] = $row;
     }
     $output = json_encode($datainfo);
     echo utf8_encode($output);    
   } else {
     echo "0";
   }

}
```

as I said it fetches "0" records on the hosting which supports PHP 5.3-5.5 and it fetches the correct number of records on my machine. The connection to the remote database (which is the same in both cases) seems successful as well.

Thanks for the insight.

**Update**

I changed my code so now I am sending the query just once:

```
mysqli_set_charset($mysqli,"utf8"); //utf-8 accents query
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);     

if (!$result) {     
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
} else {

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {            
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {              
            $datainfo[] = $row;
        }
        //utf-8 accents unescaping to be shown correctly
        $output = json_encode($datainfo,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        echo $output;                       

    } else {
        echo "0";
    }       
}
```

This works now. Thx!

Comment: Why are you sending the query twice?

Comment: Also, you're using `mysql_error()` if something goes wrong; you should be using `$mysqli->error` instead, I think

Comment: @VolkerK, you gave me a clue as to why it was not working I changed my code like the edit and now is working. Would be nice if you can tell me why on PHP 5.3-5.5 the original query was not working tho?.
Put your comment as an answer and I am gonna give the correct answer choice to you. Thx.

Comment: Sending the query twice was just superfluous and I believe it to be a good idea to throw out such stuff before testing the code line by line. You weren't testing the (second) query you were actually using to retrieve the data. So maybe it failed - some stored procedure thingy I wouldn't know...  ;-)

Comment: Anyways @VolkerK, your initial hint helped me solve the issue. If you can post it as an answer so I can give the points to you. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the suggestion of @VolkerK, this works now:

```
mysqli_set_charset($mysqli,"utf8"); //utf-8 accents query
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);     

if (!$result) {     
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
} else {

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {            
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {              
            $datainfo[] = $row;
        }
        //utf-8 accents unescaping to be shown correctly
        $output = json_encode($datainfo,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        echo $output;                       

    } else {
        echo "0";
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your table is empty in the remote server and not empry in local